# Message sent by SendMessage is not recieved in other class hierarchy

Tags: c++, mfc, sendmessage

I have two class hierarchies as shown below:

1. Class A extends CWnd

   - B extends A
   - C extends B.
2. Class D extends CWnd

   - E extends D

How can I `SendMessage` from `C` to `D`?

#### Additional information (from comments):

Message Mapping is done correctly and message is registered. Here is what I tried:

1. I call `SendMessage(...)` in a member function of class C, it's not working.
2. When I am doing it by `GetTopLevelParent()->SendMessage(...)` it is working.

But in the **second case**, it's hitting the listener function **3 times**. Can you explain why?

Comment: You are actually showing us **one class hierarchy** since all classes have a common root which is `CWnd`.

Comment: Finally, I myself added the information that has been gathered (so far) via comments. @Arjun please check if your problem is now described correctly and make corrections / improvements if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Since both classes, `C` and `D` (directly or indirectly) derive from `CWnd`, both should be able to receive messages sent via `SendMessage`. To me it's high likely that you missed something when implementing the **receiver part** in `D`.

Indeed it's not two hierarchies you have. Since the common root class is `CWnd`, it's ***one* hierarchy**:

- CWnd (common root class)

  - A (extends CWnd)

    - B (extends A)

      - C (extends B)
  - D (extends CWnd)

    - E (extends D)

You have to add a [user-defined handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/user-defined-handlers) to the message map of `D`.

```cpp
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyDoc, CDocument)
   ON_MESSAGE( <message>, <memberFxn> )
   // ...
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Read here for further information

- [User-Defined Handlers | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/user-defined-handlers)
- [Message Maps (MFC) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/message-maps-mfc)

#### Send to different `CWnd` object

As to send to an object that is of some `CWnd`-derived class, it's enough to call [`SendMessage` on it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=vs-2019#sendmessage). This is also possible without having to be "derived from `CWmd` as the sender", for example like this:

```cpp
LRESULT send_to_D(D* d) {
   return d->SendMessage(WM_APP+1, 0, 0);
}
```

#### Underlying infrastructure

MFC provide easy access to the basic Windows message transfer technology.<sup>[1]</sup> This message transfer technology is not only for passing informations but also for managing control flow. Its main goal is to provide the infrastructure for **event driven application**s. Read more here:

- [Messages and Message Queues - Win32 apps | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/messages-and-message-queues)
- [Window Procedures - Win32 apps | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-procedures)

---

<sup>[1]</sup> [Relationship Between a C++ Window Object and an HWND | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/relationship-between-a-cpp-window-object-and-an-hwnd)

Comment: Message Mapping is done correctly and message is registered. What I am trying is in class C I am writing SendMessage(Message Id, parameters) so its not working, but when I am doing like CWnd* p = GetTopLeveParent(); then p->SendMessage it is working

Comment: But its hitting the listener function 3 times not sure why?

Answer (score 0):

I read from your comments <sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61745828/message-sent-by-sendmeesage-is-not-recieved-in-other-class-hierarchy/61747992#comment109218475_61746200)</sup>

> Message Mapping is done correctly and message is registered. What I am trying is in class C I am writing SendMessage(Message Id, parameters) so its not working, but when I am doing like CWnd* p = GetTopLeveParent(); then p->SendMessage it is working

and <sup>[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61745828/message-sent-by-sendmeesage-is-not-recieved-in-other-class-hierarchy/61747992#comment109218557_61746200)</sup>

> But its hitting the listener function 3 times not sure why?

... that you are just calling `SendMessage` within some member function of `C`:

```cpp
void C::something() 
{
    SendMessage(some_msg_id, p1, p2);
}
```

But here you are actually calling `this->SendMessage(some_msg_id, p1, p2);` because in C++, each member function has an implicit `this` parameter (that is - if applicable - also implicitly used for further calls). The value of `this` within a member function is the object for which the function is currently called. So if you have an object `cObj` of class `C` and you call `cObj.something`, you invoke the member function `C::something` with the implicit parameter `this` being `cObj` for that call. If you do a call from *within* a member function, C++ checks two namespaces for resolving that call:

- global functions
- own (and inherited) member functions

In the case of own member functions, `this` is used implicitly, so you call `SendMessage` for an object of class `C`. What you want to do is calling an object of class `D`, so you need to get a pointer to some `dObj`.

When you call `GetTopLevelParent()->SendMessage(...)`, you give the message to a more general message distribution mechanism that broadcasts it to child windows. That's why you see the message more than once in your target object. But this is **only because** the `D`-class object is a child of the same top level parent as the `C`-class object.